# Best practice to adapt Laravel HTTP Request for use with multiple API's?

Tags: php, laravel, api

We consume a significant, and growing, number of API's in our project. Over the course of years, the mechanisms I've had to come up with to deal with various different API schemes have frankly become quite cumbersome.  In an effort to manage this with the most reusable code, I've started a new project using Laravel's HTTP packages, and want to eventually use it to replace all of the old code.

My approach has been to have a master "RequestManager" class the handles "Endpoint" classes with a common interface. The Endpoint classes contain everything needed for the request: the verb (POST, GET, etc.), the endpoint path, the query string, etc., and they all extend an abstract class that provides any string manipulation needed to build parameters from the arguments passed to their public methods and so forth. All this works very well, and makes it extremely easy to add new endpoints as needed.

The challenge I have at the moment is that one of the two API's I'm dealing with initially has no problem if pass the URI and an array of parameters to the Request `post` method, while the other wants the whole URI plus the query string in the first argument. Thus, this works for the first:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$request = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);

$uri = 'https://firstapi.com/get_user';
$params = [
    'name' => 'Mark',
    'email' => 'mark@example.com',
];
$response = $request->post($uri, $params);
```

While the other needs this:

```
$uri = 'https://secondapi.com/get_user?name=Mark&email=mark%40example.com';
$params = [];
$response = $request->post($uri, $params);
```

Don't ask me why, but it doesn't work otherwise.

I can't see in the Laravel docs any built-in way to handle this difference, so I've had to code a work-around:

```
$uri .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Is there something built into the Laravel code that I am perhaps missing?

Comment: _"Don't ask me why, but it doesn't work otherwise"_ ...probably just because the API in question is written in such as way that it tries to read the data from a different part of the request (i.e. querystring vs body). People don't always write their APIs in the same way, or necessarily adhere to any particular standards. Often they're not even particularly consistent within the same API. People are people, they don't always do the most logical or obvious thing. Not much you can do about that, except check their documentation.

Comment: i'm sorry, what is `$request`? something returned by `RequestManager` or what?

Comment: Anyway you say this is a "challenge", but I'm unsure, from the details provided, what exact issue this is causing you? You seem to have been able to write code which makes both styles work. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Wow, didn't expect such a rapid response.  Yes, @Adyson, I very much know that there are poorly written API's—I've dealt with dozens of them.  I'm hoping that someone with a better grasp of Laravel may know of a better way than what I've come up with.

Comment: A better way of _what_ though? That's what I mean, I'm not quite clear what you perceive the problem to be, specifcally.

Comment: At a guess, are you asking for a cleaner way to pass the querystring variables to the `->post()` function? And/or perhaps a cleaner way to pass them into your RequestManager class? You still haven't really articulated the particular difficulty. You say you've done a workaround - what from your code do you see as being the workaround - is it the ready-made querystring in the URL? That's all I can think of. But you haven't actually said so, specifically.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question: A better way of passing querystring variables when this situation arises. If the way I'm using is good enough, I guess I'll stick with it.  I am asking because I'm sure there are a lot of folks out there who have a far better grasp of Laravel HTTP than I do.

Comment: The post() function doesn't accept querystring parameters any other way (unlike the get() equivalent). It assumes anything you put into $params is to be placed in the request body instead. So all you can do really I think to make things any cleaner is, if you need to vary the values in the query string for each request, then perhaps have a bit of code in your request manager which builds up the query string from an array of key/value pairs, url-encodes each value correctly and then concatenates it together to form the equivalent to the hard-coded string in your example.

Comment: Thanks—you're correct.  I added what I'm doing now to the body of the question above, and I suppose that's what it'll have to be.  The subclasses of the Endpoint code include a $shouldConcatenateParams property to differentiate their behavior.  

I think what I was hoping for was some kind of miraculous setting on the Http class that says, in essence, "Take the array of parameters you pass into the post method, and turn them into a query string."  That's essentially what apps like Postman and Paw do.  Le sigh.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Yep I think from looking at that you're more or less doing everything you can, really. I suppose the only other option would be to subclass the relevant Laravel class and add an overload to the post function which accepts an extra array containing querystring variables, and build the querystring in there. That might count as being a "neater" solution. (Plus then you'd have flexibility for the odd API which requires a querystring value _and_ a request body).

Comment: Interesting! That didn't occur to me.  I'll suggest it and see if files.